# TV channel Identification using Linux C Programming

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-tv, ocr, video4linux

I need to develop an application which will identify the channel name which is currently running in the Television. I am using Easy CaP Video capturing device to take the video in from the dth set top boxes. Currently i am used ffmpeg to cut it into frames . then i used Tesseract OCR to read the image contents. It does not seems to be perfect. So i need some other method to implement that. Can any one help me on implementing this application.

Answer (score 0):

Call me old fashioned, but OCRing the text out of a live frame is probably the last thing I would try. The text won't always be there (will it?) and it's just a horrible way of dealing with things.

I think the only real option is to bring the capturing into the computer with a DVB card or USB stick. Then you control the channel rather than just receive it. Plus you get EPG access for free (in DVB-T/S/S2).

It's more hardware (and a slightly more convoluted setup) but much cleaner and easier to expand to handle other functions.

Comment: thank u for ur comment. But from the live video , how we will identify the channel. i just need the channel name currently running in the televison. how  can i bring into programming?